# nameerror name is not defined python 3

Tags: python

I have a Dijkstra’s algorithm. When I run this portion of my script:

```
graph = {}

graph["begin"] = {}

graph["begin"]["a"] = 6

graph["begin"]["b"] = 2 

graph["begin"]["c"] = 3

graph["begin"]["d"] = 1 

graph["a"] = {}

graph["a"]["c"] = 3

graph["b"] = {}

graph["b"]["a"] = 3

graph["b"]["d"] = 5

graph["d"] = {}

graph["d"]["fin"] = 1

graph["c"] = {}

graph["c"]["d"] = 1

graph["c"]["fin"] = 3

graph["fin"] = {} 


infinity = float("inf")

costs = {}

costs["a"] = 6

costs["b"] = 2

costs["c"] = infinity 

costs["d"] = infinity

costs["fin"] = infinity 


parents = {}

parents["a"] = ["begin"]

parents["b"] = ["begin"]

parents["c"] = ["begin"]

parents["d"] = ["begin"]

parents["fin"] = None 



processed = [] 

def find_lowest_cost_node(costs):

  lowest_cost = float("inf")

  lowest_cost_node = None

  for node in costs:

    cost = costs[node]

    if cost < lowest_cost and node not in processed:

      lowest_cost = cost

      lowest_cost_node = node

  return lowest_cost_node


def run_dijkstra():

  node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)

  while node is not None:

    neighbors = graph[node]

    for neighbor in neighbors.keys():

      newcost = neighbors[neighbor] + costs[node]

      if newcost < costs[neighbor]:

        costs[neighbor] = newcost

        parents[neighbor] = node

    processed.append(node)

    node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)

  return 

  def print_path(begin, fin):
print ["cost to destination", str(costs["fin"])]

     print ["fin"]

  nextNode = parents[end]

  while nextNode != begin:

    print ["nextNode"]

    nextNode = parents[nextNode]

  print ["begin"]


run_dijkstra()

print_path("begin, end")
```

I get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 70, in
>    NameError: name 'print_path' is not defined

Does anyone know a decision of this problem?)

Answer (score 1):

Check the alignment within the `print_path(begin, end)` function (possibly a copy/paste issue, but as it is it will not work)

The function declaration is `print_path(begin, end)`, but it is called as `print_path("begin, end")`, so with a single string argument. Try `print_path("begin", "end")`

Comment: Also, make sure your indentations are correct after the function def statement.